# Apache Kafka Single Node Docker- how to set listener to docker hostname

Tags: docker, kafka

I am using the Apache Kafka `3.7.0` docker image as outlined [here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_startserver), with some minor tweaks:

`docker run --network=internal --name my-kafka apache/kafka:3.7.0`

My intention is to only access this within the internal network, and access it by its hostname `my-kafka`. As this command stands, it seems to run fine and uses Kraft out of the box based on the logs:

```
INFO [raft-expiration-reaper]: Starting (kafka.raft.TimingWheelExpirationService$ExpiredOperationReaper)
INFO Initialized snapshots with IDs SortedSet() from /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/__cluster_metadata-0 (kafka.r>
INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Producer state recovery took >
INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-combined-logs] Reloading from producer snaps>
```

However, by default the advertised listeners are only configured for `localhost`, breaking connections from client (which connects via the hostname `my-kafka`). I have attempted to set some environment variables to set new listeners with the relevant hostname:

`docker run --network=internal --name my-kafka -e KAFKA_LISTENERS=LISTENER_FRED://my-kafka:9092 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=LISTENER_FRED://my-kafka:9092 -e KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT apache/kafka:3.7.0`

This results in the exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration 'zookeeper.connect'`. It seems that it attempts to run with Zookeeper instead of Kraft, but only when the env vars are provided?

As far as I can tell, I am setting the advertised listeners correctly, and based on looking around the latest docker image behaves a little differently that others expect? What can I do to get my Kafka server working?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sample docker-compose could help you with the environment variables:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/docker/examples/jvm/single-node/plaintext/docker-compose.yml

I had a similar issue while trying to configure a kafka deployment inside a k3d cluster (just for local development) using the configuration below (note the service and port: `kafka.kafka.svc:9094` which is used by the consumers inside the cluster).

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kafka-properties
  namespace: kafka
data:
  KAFKA_NODE_ID: '1'
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka.kafka.svc:9094'
  KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
  KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@localhost:29093'
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'CONTROLLER://:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092,PLAINTEXT://:9094'
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
  KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
  CLUSTER_ID: '4L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw'
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: '0'
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: '1'
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
  KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kafka
  labels:
    app: kakfa
spec:
  replicas: 1

  revisionHistoryLimit: 3

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kakfa

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kakfa

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: apache/kafka:3.7.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: kafka-properties

          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
              name: internal

            - containerPort: 9094
              name: external

          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "500m"

            limits:
              memory: "5Gi"
              cpu: "3"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kafka
  labels:
    app: kakfa
spec:
  selector:
    app: kakfa

  ports:
    - name: internal
      port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9092

    - name: external
      port: 9094
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9094
```